# How do you change the interpolation for a zoom behavior in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using d3.js V 4.0 to provide zooming and panning in an SVG. I am implementing a reset button to get me back to the center of the image. It is working, but it is using the default d3.interpolateZoom so the image zooms way out during the transition. I just want the scaling to do standard interpolation, but I cant figure out how to change the interpolator for the zoom behavior.
Here is an abbreviated version of the code:

```js
var map = document.querySelector('#map');
var everything = d3.select('#everything');
var zoomBehavior = d3.zoom();
zoomBehavior.scaleExtent([0.5, 10])
  .on('zoom', zoomed);
d3.select(map).call(zoomBehavior);

function zoomed() {
  everything.attr('transform', d3.event.transform);
}

function reset() {
  d3.select(this.map)
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .call(zoomBehavior.transform, d3.zoomIdentity);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.1.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="map" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g id="everything">
    <circle r="5" cx="50" cy="15"></circle>
  </g>
</svg>
<button onclick="reset()">reset</button>
```

Unfortunately this is not exhibiting the behavior I am seeing. (In my real version the scale k interpolates through 0 using the [van Wijk smooth zooming](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3828981)) But the question is still valid. If I were to change the interpolator for this zoom behavior, how and where would I do that? I have tried calling zoomBehavior.interpolate(d3.interpolate) that the documentation seems to suggest, but I get an error stating that zoomBehavior.interpolate is not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's tough to answer this without seeing the behavior you are trying to avoid.  Your sample code above works as expected.  That said, here's an example of taking complete control of the interpolaters and hence the transition.  Here I'm zooming the circle back to `scale: 1` but `x` and `y` to the lower right of the svg:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <svg id="map" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g id="everything">
      <circle r="5" cx="50" cy="15"></circle>
    </g>
  </svg>
  <button onclick="reset()">reset</button>
  <script>
    var map = d3.select('#map'),
        everything = d3.select('#everything');

    var zoomBehavior = d3.zoom();
    zoomBehavior.scaleExtent([0.5, 10])
      .on('zoom', zoomed);

    map.call(zoomBehavior);

    function zoomed() {
      everything.attr('transform', d3.event.transform);
    }

    function reset() {
      d3.select(this.map)
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .tween("custom", function() {
          var curZoom = d3.zoomTransform(map.node()),
            kInter = d3.interpolate(curZoom.k, 1),
            xInter = d3.interpolate(curZoom.x, 240),
            yInter = d3.interpolate(curZoom.y, 99);
          return function(t) {
            var ts = d3.zoomIdentity
              .translate(xInter(t), yInter(t))
              .scale(kInter(t));
            map.call(zoomBehavior.transform, ts);
          };
        });
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: While your example works great in the code snippet, when I try it in my own code, the function returned in the tween is only called once, so the transform doe snot really happen. Any idea what would cause this to only fire once instead of repeatedly for the duration?

Comment: @EricJ, very difficult to say on the limited information you've given.  Can you create a reproducible example with your specific code?

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the issue in a snippet, or on any other system. There must be something wrong with that system.

Answer (score 5):

We had the same problem and solved it by using the `interpolate` method. Applied to your code it would look like this:

```
zoomBehavior.interpolate(d3.interpolate).scaleExtent([0.5, 10])
  .on('zoom', zoomed);
```

According to http://devdocs.io/d3~4/d3-zoom#zoom_interpolate, `d3.interpolate` applies "direct interpolation between two views" whereas the default is `d3.interpolateZoom` which applies "smooth zooming" that neither of us want.

Comment: OMG, I was going to write a tween function until I saw this. So trivial!

Answer (score 0):

Note you can now use `.rho` in [d3.interpolateZoom](https://github.com/d3/d3-interpolate#interpolateZoom) (v2.0.1) to customize the amount of curvature you get while zooming and panning. The default is `Math.sqrt(2)` while `rho(0)` results in linear interpolation.

This is how you would set it up:

```
let zoomBehavior = d3.zoom()
    .interpolate(d3.interpolateZoom.rho(0.9)) // 0.9 for less curvature
    .scaleExtent([0.5, 10])
    .on('zoom', zoomed);
```